# Listview with scrolling background image

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, mvvm

I am trying to create a `ListView` that looks like items sitting on a shelf. I am able to get the shelf background on the list view like so:

```
<ListView.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\bookshelf.png" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Top" TileMode="Tile" Stretch="None" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,319,203" />
</ListView.Background>
```

but when doing it this way the background is static and doesn't move when the `ListView` scrolls. I figure I have to add this to the scrollview of the `ListView` somehow but I'm not sure how.

How do I add an image that tiles and scrolls with the `ListView`?

Comment: Have you tried setting the background of each row of the LV to a single shelf?

Comment: Thing to note with ListView is with it's virtualization, ActualHeight of the ScrollViewer is not actually it's total height. It uses a combination of `ExtentHeight`, `ScrollableHeight`, `ViewportHeight`, `VerticalOffset` and possibly something else as well to compute it's actual scroll-bar requirements and scroll dimensions. Even with all of this it's not guaranteed to be right if say some item not in the Viewport has a much bigger `Height` than other items as you can see the scrollbar thumb size adjust when this irregular item enter's the viewport.

Comment: ^^..contd. With the possibility that we cannot calculate the actual `ExtentHeight` with Virtualisation and un-even item height's, @GarryVass 's suggestion would be the best option for you here. Slice the book-shelf image into 3 parts(top, shelf, bottom) and either use a DataTemplate selector to apply them respectively, or wrap the ListView with the top and bottom images outside it and apply the shelf image to each item.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the background of the ListView, try creating another ScrollViewer which is behind the ListView and contains an image. When the ListView is scrolled, update the ScrollViewer scroll position. This will also allow you to add parallax scrolling if you wanted it.