# WPF - Is it possible to have ListBox background to scroll together with scrollbar?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a `ListBox` and I mapped the background with tiled `ImageBrush`. When I have a lot of items in the `ListBox` and scroll it down, the background stays in the same position.

Is it possible to have the background to scroll together with scrollbar? If so, how?

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}">
    <ListBox.Background>
       <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://application:,,,/NS;Assets/background.png" TileMode="Tile" ViewPortUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,400,300"/>
    </ListBox.Background>
</ListBox>
```

Note that the background is bigger than the `ListBoxItem`, so I can't map the `ImageBrush` background to the `ListBoxItem` instead.

Comment: Try the suggestion here: [Listview with scrolling background image](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17913691/6741868). Although its a listview, it might work for listbox as well.

Comment: Thanks, my question looks the same. But, which suggestion is good? I don't see accepted answer and @GarryVass' suggestion is not even there.

Comment: The only answer to that question seems like it will work, but it requires quite some coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly more elegant ways to do this, but one simple alternative is to do as follows:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Image Source="MyBackground.png" Stretch="None" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ItemsContainer}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemsContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

*@edit*
or tiled:

```
<ScrollViewer>
    <Grid>
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=ItemsContainer}">
            <Grid.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="MyBackground.png" TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="[...]" Viewport="[...]" />
            </Grid.Background>
        </Grid>
        <ListBox x:Name="ItemsContainer" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The result would be:

[image: Output]

Comment: @kurakura88 Edited the answer to add a tiled version

Comment: Thanks! My `ListBox` can adjust in size, therefore instead of `...Height="{Binding ActualHeight,...`, I used `MaxHeight="{Binding ActualHeight,...`